# Check cpu usage of Javascript application

Tags: javascript

I made a web application and everytime it overwarm my laptop and goes very slow. I think it depends by some function bad coded. How can I check it?

Comment: Use Chrome dev tools to see what function is giving you grief.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling